# $a^3+b^3+c^3 + 21abc \geq 3$ for $(a+b)(a+c)(b + c) = 1$ and $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$a, b, c \gt 0$ and $(a+b)(a+c)(b + c) = 1$ Prove that $a^3+b^3+c^3 + 21abc \geq 3$

In this problem I spotted one trick

$(a+b)(a+c)(b + c) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \\(a \sqrt{b+c})^2+(b\sqrt{a+c})^2+(c \sqrt{b+c})^2+2(a\sqrt{b+c})(b\sqrt{a+c})(c\sqrt{a+b}) = 1$

That says for positive $x$, $y$, $z$ reals if $x^2+y^2+z^2+2xyz = 1$ then $x = \cos \alpha$, $y = \cos \beta$, $z = \cos \gamma$.

Trigonometric substitutions can be done where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are angles of triangle.  So we can let,

$\cos \alpha = a\sqrt{b+c}$, $\cos \beta = b\sqrt{a+c}$, $\cos \gamma=c\sqrt{a+b}$

How can I continue to complete this proof?

I  am  sure  there  is  another  useful  proof  of  the  problem  but  I  tried  to  get  the  original  proof  but  unfortunately  I  could  not.  Can  you  help  me?  Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a continuation of the given solution or an 'elementary' proof without cosines?

Comment: no  i  want  to  complete  the  proof  with  cosines

Comment: no  problem  you  can  give  your personl  solution

Comment: Plugging in some numbers, it seems that the inequality is just wrong. Perhaps you mixed up something?

Comment: it  is  not  my  problem  can  you  give  a  counterexample?

Comment: this  problem  belongs  to  my  friend

Comment: Well, I took $a=b=\frac{1}{3}$ and solved for $c$. working it out, it comes out wrong - the inequality is reversed. However for other values of $a,b,c$ the inequality is correct.

Comment: Please retype your question in latex to make it searchable, to be useful to everyone using the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is not true.

$a=\dfrac{1}{6},b=\dfrac{2}{6},c=\dfrac{7}{6} \to $ LHS$=2.99 <3$

$a=\dfrac{33}{140},b=\dfrac{37}{140},c=\dfrac{163}{140} \to$ LHS$=3.12 >3$

Comment: ok  thanks  you  are  right  there  is  problem  on  inequality